# QBFC sales order query, are filters ORED or anded?

Tags: sdk, quickbooks, qbfc

Wondering if using QBFC 13 the filters can be combined and run at once?  For instance, I have a SO query, and I need to run and say "return all orders created or modified within the last week".  It looks like there are two areas for this in the OSR.

SalesOrderQuery.ORTxnNoAccountQuery.TxnFilterNoAccount.ORDateRangeFilter.FromModifiedDate
SalesOrderQuery.ORTxnNoAccountQuery.TxnFilterNoAccount.ORDateRangeFilter.ToModifiedDate

Can these be combined with the fromTxnDate and ToTxnDate as an "OR"?  I see the "or" embedded in there, not sure if this means it's an "or", or "object relationship" ;)  Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you just run a qbXML query with a `FromModifiedDate` clause, it will give you exactly what you want.

Orders have their `FromModifiedDate` timestamp set when they are created as well as modified, so you can use `FromModifiedDate` to get orders that were created or modified within a date/time range.

There is no way to OR/AND the queries, but you don't need to do that anyway if you use the above approach.

Comment: Nice!  Thank you, you answered both questions and will help me with this type of thing in the future :)